# Conversion of ROS Bag to CSV Extremely Slow

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have gathered data using `rosbag`, but listing topics from it and extracting data from it is *extremely* slow. It takes over an hour to process a `.bag` file that is 180 MB in size and contains 47 data streams, with output file sizes ranging from 330 bytes to 23 MB. It's operating principle is similar to the answer by user `x75` in a [closely related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/).

Is there anything I can do to improve the parsing speed? My guess is that it is going through the file in full each time, whereas in reality I could save and reuse information from the `.bag` file in the first pass so I don't have to re-read the whole file every time I extract topic data from it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bagfile="${1##*/}"
bagfile="${bagfile%.*}"

# Create the output directory.
mkdir -p $bagfile

topic_list_orig=`rostopic list -b $1`
topic_list=$(echo "$topic_list_orig" | sort)

for topic in $topic_list
do 
    outfname="$bagfile/${topic//\//_}.csv"
    echo "Writing CSV data from topic" $topic "to file" $outfname
    
    # Check if file exists. If file exists, do not write to it.
    if [ -e $outfname ]
    then
        echo "File" $outfname "already exists. Taking no action"
    else
        # Create a temporary file
        tmpfile=`mktemp`
        echo $tmpfile
        rostopic echo -p -b $1 $topic > $tmpfile
        
        # Copy temp file into the final file.
        mv $tmpfile $outfname
    fi
done

##### END OF FILE #####
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195533/conversion-of-ros-bag-to-csv-extremely-slow/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct; it is reading through the bag file once for each topic.

Take a look at the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) and the [rosbag cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) for some examples of better ways to extract data from bag files.

You may be able to use the same message to CSV conversion that rostopic uses if you're clever about it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-10-23**:
I had a look at the examples but they don't cover the case of converting to CSV directly. I know there is a Python API for writing CSV files but it would be good to know how it works with the rosbag API.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-23**:
It may be useful to read the portion of rospy which converts messages to CSV format: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/2c4af852eafd5335dc2dff7446a1879519a8e2b6/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L503

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-23**:
It may be more productive to instantiate a [CallbackEcho](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/2c4af852eafd5335dc2dff7446a1879519a8e2b6/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L586) object and use that, rather than calling the private functions of rostopic directly.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-10-27**:
I will have a look at that. Just note that I will probably need to process about 10 more sets of data, at 1-1.5 hours per piece, or less if I am more selective about the topics I extract. It seems like the time taken to have to learn the new API will not be justified in my case. Am I correct?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-27**:
If you know Python, it'll probably take 2-4 hours to write the appropriate script. You may also want to try the `bag2csv.py` answer from the question that you linked to. I wouldn't be suggesting this approach if I thought it was a waste of your time.